# Is it possible to add sounds and effects to an animation plist in Cocos2D

Tags: ios, animation, cocos2d-iphone

I am new to Cocos2D. I am working with a couple of people on a interactive "book" with a few small games for young people (below 4 years) that can not read. 
I started by building a background (Cocos2D) and am able to add Sprites (using SpriteSheets, and TexturePacker) and animate those with use of plists. I wonder if it is possible to add sound-effects in the plist. For example: one of the Sprites has an animation "screaming". It would be very nice if the corresponding sound was incorporated in the plist! This also enables the animations and sounds being created by the more artistic people.
My experience is to small to write this code all by myself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are many ways to do this, but i dont think that the animations plist format should be mangled to support some other purpose. I tend to create 'metadata' (in plist format also, but could be in a database) for situations like this. Generally this metadata is loaded in core at game start, forever. For example, from one of my games, the following code:

```
    [self addToDictionary:dic
                  key:@"improvedCheapShot" 
                 name:@"Cheap Shot +" 
    characterClassKey:@"rogue" 
          rankInClass:3 costBP:3 skillSpeed:2 skillPower:150   skillRange:0 
           isMapSkill:NO isMultiTargetSkill:NO
       isHealingSkill:NO isProtectingSkill:NO
           damageType:geDamageTypePhysical 
         effectImpact:geEffectImpactNotApplicable
              toolTip:@"Strikes the weakest foe in melee range, ignoring its defense. Damage is increased by 20%." 
              soundFx:@"sound_fx_skill_sword5.mp3"
  damageAnimationSpec:[GECombatDamageAnimation damageMagicAnimation:geDamageMagicAnimationSoldier   
                                                            playerFile:nil
                                                               CPUfile:@"magie_cheapShot"
                                                                frames:15]


 ];
```

This is from my singleton class for combatSkillSpecifications , just one skill shown (of many). In there i keep all information required for the 'skillExecutionController' and 'skillAnimationSequencer'.

I am convinced your game will in the end require multiple instances of coordination between animation and sound play.

Comment: It would be better if it were not Polish Christmas tree notation! -.-

Comment: actually reversedPolishChrismasTreeNotation .... started by playing with HP gear as a kid.

Comment: OK. I don't know if I understand it completely, but at least I have a direction for a solution. Thnx.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no such procedure but you can manage that by scheduling a selector for that

Like:

For scheduling `[self schedule:@selector(playSound) interval:1.0f];`

```
-(void)playSound
{
      [[SimpleAudioEngine SharedEngine]playEffect:@"sound1.mp3"];
      [self unschedule:@selector(playSound)];
}
```

Comment: I see the possibility, and I like the simplicity of the solution. Have to think it over. Thnx.